# How to perform ac to dc voltage conversion and vice versa?

Tags: voltage-measurement, math

In india household voltage is 230Vac ,50Hz. Suppose i have a SMPS that coverts 230vac into 5Vdc.

Here, I want to know what is dc voltage equivalent of 230Vac and what is ac voltage equivalent value of 5Vdc? Is there any formula to perform this above calculations?
So can anybody tell whether below mathematical calcultions are right or wrong

**As per my knowledge**

Vdc= Vaverage  ---(eq1)

now,

Vaverage= 0.693 *Vpeak---(eq2)

and

Vac=Vrms   --(eq3)

Vac= 0.707* Vpeak---(eq4)

so from equations 1,2,3& 4

**Vac= (0.707/0.693) * Vdc i.e. 1.1*Vdc** is it right??

So, as per above relation
230Vac equivalent to (230/1.1) i.e. 210Vdc

and 5Vdc equivalent to (5*1.1) i.e. 5.5 Vac

Comment: *110Vdc,60Hz* - Wat? it's AC. There is no meaning for frequency if it is DC.

Comment: @EugeneSh. sorry question edited

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking about anyway. What do you mean by "equivalent"?

Comment: I think he's asking about RMS

Comment: @EugeneSh. I want to know the relation between AC voltage and DC voltage .

Comment: @EugeneSh. is the above question still not clear?

Comment: @efox29 is question clear now?

Answer (score 2):

In terms of heating value including in incandescent lights, 110Vac is equal to 110Vdc. In terms of operating a universal motor, the dc voltage should probably be a little lower, but there is no exact conversion. However the standard USA household voltage is 120Vac, 60Hz  with 240Vac, 60Hz also supplied but normally only connected to cooking stove (range) and laundering outlets and directly to water heaters and central air conditioners.

Where DC is used, AC power is rectified inside appliances or chargers. Virtually no DC power is distributed by utilities.

The above does not answer the question as edited, but regardless of the voltage, RMS AC voltage is equal to the same value DC voltage in terms of heating value. There is no other direct relationship.

Full-wave rectified single-phase AC voltage, if unfiltered, is equivalent to AC voltage less the voltage drop of the diodes for heating and incandescent light purposes and probably also for universal motors. At the 120 and 240 volt levels the diode drop is less than the normal voltage fluctuation of the best utility supplies. Rectified AC voltage that is well filtered is equivalent to the peak of the AC voltage waveform, 1.414 X the RMS value.